# splitting a string by a list

Tags: python, list

How do I split a string according to the variables in a given list? 
 
(I am using python 2.7).
 
for example:

```py
given_list = ['c', 'c#', 'd', 'd#', 'e', 'f', 'f#', 'g', 'g#', 'a', 'a#', 'b']
st="c#cd#e"
```

expected result:

```py
new_list = ['c#','c', 'd#', 'e']
```

The problem is that some of the variables start with the same letter. The program will not look at the # sign, but at the first letter. 
 
 Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I have tried to use split(), but I don't find a method to separate the string without a specific sign.

Comment: I would use loop which use line like `if st.startwith('c'):` and if it starts with `c` then cut off this part.

Comment: `split` wont work here. You have to make a specific code. If an error occurs please share it with us. We are ready to solve it. I know the answer but I won't be sharing it unless you share your code

Comment: d in st could be d or d#, how would the algo know which to pick

Comment: @AnswerSeeker code would have to first check longer elements - first `d#` next `d`. Luckly there is no `#` on the list because then `d#` could be treated as `[ d# ]` or `[ d, #]` and it can make problem.

Answer (score 5):

Use `'|'.join()` to make a regex pattern from your given_list, with a trick to sort the list with those notes with '#' comes first by reverse alphetical order

```py
import re

given_list = ['c', 'c#', 'd', 'd#', 'e', 'f', 'f#', 'g', 'g#', 'a', 'a#', 'b']
given_list= sorted(given_list, reverse=True)
# ['g#', 'g', 'f#', 'f', 'e', 'd#', 'd', 'c#', 'c', 'b', 'a#', 'a']
st="c#cd#e"
new_list = re.findall('|'.join(given_list), st)
```

```py
print(new_list)
# ['c#', 'c', 'd#', 'e']
```

EDIT: use `reverse=True` in `sorted(given_list,reverse=True)` as suggested by @HenryYik

Comment: Or just pass `reverse=True` in `sorted(given_list,reverse=True)`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work specifically in your case.

```py
new_list = list()
for x in list(st):
    if x!='#':
        new_list.append(x)
    else:
        new_list[-1] += '#'

new_list
```

**Output**:

```
['c#', 'c', 'd#', 'e']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the `given_list` by reverse alphetical order so any item that contains # will be in head  of the list. I sorted it because if i wanted to take 'c' from string, it might be taken 'c#'s 'c'. After that, you can go through `given_list`'s items and if `st` contains item, we append our `result` list. For deleting item in `st` i am using replace method.

```
result=[]
given_list= sorted(given_list,reverse=true)
for item in given_list:
    if item in st:
        st=st.replace(item,'')
        result.append(item)
print(result)
# ['e', 'd#', 'c#', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to read through the string and check if either the next or the next 2 letters appear in your `given_list`. If it does you can append this piece to a new list.

```
given_list = ['c', 'c#', 'd', 'd#', 'e', 'f', 'f#', 'g', 'g#', 'a', 'a#', 'b']
st="c#cxd#e"

result = []
while len(st) > 0:
  if len(st) > 1 and st[0:2] in given_list:
    result.append(st[0:2])
    st = st[2:]
  elif st[0:1] in given_list:
    result.append(st[0:1])
    st = st[1:]
  else:
    # You probably want to raise some error if the string is not compliant.
    raise KeyError("A sequence of the string does not exist in given_list")

print result
# ['c#', 'c', 'd#', 'e']
```

This approach works quite well even if you add new variants to your 'given_list'. As long as they are only 2 letters long max.